# Logging MyFaces 2.0

Tags: logging, jsf-2, myfaces

I've upgrade MyFaces Core 2.0.5 to 2.0.8 and stopped receiving runtime exceptions logs.
Something in the logging mechanism changed that hides the exception messages.

To test this, I planted this code in the bean:

```
logger.trace("XXX BEFORE XXX");
((AdminBean)(null)).deiChanged("DfdfD");
logger.trace("XXX AFTER XXX");
```

And I can see that the log (and tomcat console) print `XXXX BEFORE XXXX` so I know for sure that a null pointer exception was thrown.

So, How should I handle run time exceptions? I'm just referring to logging them at this point but if I have to create a handler, than I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using JSF2.1 and then I do indeed need a handler. From [GoJava](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2010/09/jsf-2-exception-handling.html) it seems that 2.0 also needs one.

MAG,
Milo van der Zee